# How to refer to a word created via $randomWord in Postman

Tags: json, rest, testing, postman

I have a query that generates a key with a random name:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://apitest.backendless.com/A1DA5DF0-8D22-BAC4-FF56-9A0074DC9B00/8834B7F8-88BD-4472-9051-71BE31A3EE5B/hive/rootKeys/set/{{$randomWord}}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '["123", true]'
```

The query itself returns the length of the new key. In the tests, I check that the key length is actually returned:

```
let response = pm.response.json();

pm.test("Created new key", () => {
    pm.expect(response, "Error").to.eql(2)
});
```

But I still need to check the completeness of this key (that is, check that the key was created with the specified values).
The question is, how do I refer to this word that was generated via `{{$randomWord}}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replaceIn()` to get dynamic variables in postman.

- Step 1: In `Pre-req` tab, get value from `{{$randomWord}}` --> save it to variables/environment scope.

```
let randomWord = pm.variables.replaceIn("{{$randomWord}}");
pm.variables.set("randomWord", randomWord);
```

- Step 2: Use it in postman UI. In this case, it's in URL

[image]

- Step 3: Get it in `Test` tab and do your work.

```
let rdWord = pm.variables.get("randomWord");
//do your assertion
```